# Angular smart/dumb components vs. switching views using Router, which is better and why?

Tags: angular

For example, I have 2 views: List and Add/Edit.

Is it better to have a smart container component which handles fetching data from services and has previously mentioned views as child/dumb components.

Or, do the switch between views with Router and fetch service data from each separate view component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the angular routing for this. In particular because it comes with some handy advantages:

- When the user reloads the page, they stay on the same view without the need to store parts of your state in the session. This also enables users to copy a link and send it to someone else or bookmark certain views of your application.
- It scales better. This might not make a difference for a small application with only two views, but for bigger ones it is way more convenient to extend a route tree rather than having huge switch-case statements deciding which view to show.
- There's built in featues like the RouterLink directive to easily navigate to routes.
- Using routes enables you to use all kindsd of handy stuff like guards, resolvers and so on. Not using The angular router means you need to implement those behaviors on your on if you need them in the future.
- If your application grows, using the router enables you to lazy load submodules.

Most of these points are especially relevant for medium to large applications and are not that important for very small applications. So if you really only have two views and are not planning to extend your application, it probably does not make a big difference. But for a potentially growing application, I'd go with the routing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly but lets call previous requests, data, store actions etc. a state. I would save this state in a singleton service. Store previous state in a service when user does something in the view constantly overwriting the state. So when a user leaves and returns to the component, it's state will be taken from a service (if there is something to take) - a cache if you will. One way could be to set the data on actions, and OnInit to get the state from the service.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
 _state;

 get state() {
  return this._state;
 }

 set state(data) {
  this._state = data
 }
}
```

```
export class StateComponent {
 // inject state service to access set get methods
 constructor(private service: StateService) {
  this.service.state =  { data: moredata }; // setting state

  console.log(this.service.state); // getting state from anywhere 
}
```

Otherwise known as state management. https://blog.logrocket.com/angular-state-management-made-simple-with-ngr

If you would have "smart container" system you would still need to store the state somewhere, else if the components get destroyed, so will the state.

Comment: Nope, not what I meant. Edited my question to hopefully make it more clear. But thanks for the input